# .htaccess redirect all subdirectories to root (Kinda)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is not as straight forward as the title might imply. I'll try to explain.

I'm currently working on a video website based on rewritten urls.
I'm using this rule currently:

> RewriteEngine on
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond
>   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

This is used to let users access videos with good looking urls like this:

**domain.com/kJbSGe5X** instead of **domain.com/?v=kJbSGe5X** or **domain.com/index.php?v=kJbSGe5X** for example.

Now the problem is that whenever a trailing slash is added, the css breaks. 
I've tried solutions like adding a slash in front of the css url, like this:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

... but it's not working.

Could a solution be to rewrite all urlstrings after a trailing slash (including the trailing slash) to the same url, without the trailing string? Like this:

**domain.com/kJbSGe5X/** or **domain.com/kJbSGe5X/randomchars** to this:
**domain.com/kJbSGe5X** - and how would I go about doing so?

I guess there probably is much better solutions to this problem, but I'm rather new at this.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**--EDIT--**

I would prefer a solution where everything after a trailing slash gets redirected to the same url without the trailing slash + any string after the trailing. (If there is no content in said url)

I might have put to much emphasis on the css issue - A rule like this would work great with how my website is setup.

Answer (score 1):

Insert this rule **before your existing rule** to remove any trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^/]+)/.*?\sHTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Nice! Is there also a way to remove the trailing slash -and- any string that comes after the slash?

Comment: `any string that comes after the slash` I believe you mean query string. For that see updated code.

Comment: I want it to work like this if possible:
**domain.com/akkajd/adadoj** gets rewritten to **domain.com/akkajd**.
Thanks for any reply! :)

Comment: Do I have to be on a live server to use it?
I'm currently on localhost, and with the updated rule, when I add trailing slash (and anything after), I get redirected to "/HTTP".

Comment: I had a mistake. Corrected it now. Can you try.

Comment: I found a solution that worked for me. With a little help from you. Check my answer! Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try ignoring the css directory in your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/
```

This isn't exactly what you asked for but if you excluded specific directories from your rewrite rule (probably /css, /js and so on) then you would not have to worry about formatting your nice/short view URLs to remove anything after the slash or whatever else.

Comment: I like the idea of this. I tried to add it to my .htaccess together with the existing rules.But I can't seem to get it to work. The css still breaks when adding a trailing slash. I guess I'm doing something wrong. Could you update your post and combine that rule with the rules I listed in the OP? :)

I should mabye add that I'm doing all this on localhost - if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my complete solution. With a little help from anubhava!

**Remove trailing slash from all urls:**

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
>
> RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

**Constrain the "create goodlooking" urls thingy to only work when it's 8 characters (which is the length of each shortlink for videos):**

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteRule ^(.{8})$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]